# If i create a disconnected ADO recordset from scratch in VBA how do i set the base table information for UpdateBatch?

Tags: vba, adodb

I have been using disconnected recordsets for a few weeks now, typically retrieving data from SQL Server, disconnecting the rs and filtering/formatting in VBA. Now i'm trying to do the reverse and create a new ADO recordset from scratch, and then connect it to my database and use UpdateBatch to insert the recordset into the database without using a loop. I have a fully populated recordset at this point, hooked it back up to my connection string, and try UpdateBatch. Understandably, it has no information at this point about what table I'm trying to update (only Data Source and Initial Catalog via the connection string). Is there a recordset property that I use to provide the table in question? Additionally, the table I'm trying to import into has a GUID field (first field) that I have left blank on purpose in my disconnected recordset assuming that upon import, SQL Server would assign this GUID/primary key automatically.

The specific error I'm getting after "rs.UpdateBatch" is 
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'"
Insufficient base table information for updating or refreshing.

I know I could use a loop and a SQL command "INSERT INTO ...". I'd like to use a recordset object though since those provide much more functionality as a container for data. One thing I haven't tried is to first retrieve a recordset from the table in question, then clear it and re-populate it with the new data so that the recordset itself retains all of the original database and table properties. If that's the only/best approach I can try that route too. I just wanted to see if it was possible to create an ADO recordset, populate it, and then insert it into a matching table of my choice.

```
dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs.Fields
    .append "alias", adVarChar, 255
    .append "textA", adVarChar, 255
    .append ......
End With

rs.Open
rs.AddNew Array(0, 1, 2, ..., n), Array(val0, val1, val2, ..., valn)
rs.Update

call importRS(rs)

rs.close
set rs = nothing
```

---

After rs.update above some recordsets may need to go to a database, other recordset objects are just used to expedite filtering and sorting so I just use them as a convenient container and they'd never go to importRS()

However, IF I need to send the disconnected recordset to a database, i'd like to just pass the recordset object to another function that serves the purpose of opening the connection, sending the update, and closing the connection. The code below would serve that purpose which is why i'd like to wait to establish a connection until this point, right at the end after my rs is populated.

```
sub importRS(byref rs as ADODB.Recordset)
dim cn as ADODB.Connection
set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = strConnection 'my connection string variable'
cn.Open

rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.UpdateBatch '-------error message appears on this line

cn.close
set cn = nothing
```

Comment: Yes this can be done. I am writing up a working example below.

Comment: Check out the updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data, (wherever it may be) into an array and add to the recordset using a loop. Then then when the loop is finished, you do `rs.updatebatch` as follows:

```vb
Private Sub SaveToSQLSever()

 Dim lngLastRow As Long 
 Dim arrySheet As Variant
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim strCn As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    strCn= "Provider=VersionOfSQL;User ID=*********;Password=*********;" 
               & _ "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName"

    cn.Open strCn

    On Error Goto exiting
    '*********************************************************
    'If the data is coming from a sheet
    'Set to your Range
    With Sheets("SheetName")
        lngLastRow = .Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows _ 
        (.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count).Row
        arrySheet = .Range("A1:G" & lngLastRow).Value2      
    End With

    'Else populate the array and pass it to this Sub 
    '*************************************************************
        'Note the property parameters
        '.Source = Table That you want to populate
        With rs 
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .Source = "Select * from TableName"   
            .CursorType = adOpenDynamic           
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient         
            .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
            .Open
        End With

        For i = LBound(arrySheet,1) To UBound(arrySheet,1) 
           rs.AddNew
           For j = LBound(arrySheet,2) To UBound(arrySheet,2) 
               rs.Fields(j).Value = arrySheet(i,j)
           Next j 
           rs.MoveNext
        Next i 

    rs.UpdateBatch 'Updates the table with additions from the array

       i = 0
       '******************************************************************
       'Note that you can also refer to the Field Names Explicitly Like So: 
        For i = LBound(arryData,1) To UBound(arryData,1) 
            With rs 
               .AddNew

               .Fields("FieldName1").Value = arryData(i,1)
               .Fields("FieldName2").Value = arryData(i,2)
               .Fields("FieldName3").Value = arryData(i,3)
               .Fields("FieldName4").Value = arryData(i,4)
               .Fields("FieldName5").Value = arryData(i,5)
               .Fields("FieldName6").Value = arryData(i,6)
               .Fields("FieldName7").Value = arryData(i,7)
            End With 
        Next i

       rs.UpdateBatch
      '******************************************************************
    MsgBox "The data has successfully been saved to the SQL Server", _ 
    vbInformation + vbOKOnly,"Alert: Upload Successful"

exiting:
    If cn.State > 0 Then cn.Close
    If rs.State > 0 Then rs.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Edit:** As per OP's request to pass an existing recordset to a SQL table, below should do so:

```
Private Sub SendRcrdsetToSQL(ByRef rsIn As ADODB.Recordset)

 Dim arrySheet As Variant
 Dim rsSQL As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim strCn As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    strCn= "Provider=VersionOfSQL;User ID=*********;Password=*********;" 
               & _ "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName"

    cn.Open strCn

    On Error Goto exiting
    Set rsSQL = New ADODB.Recordset
        With rsSQL 
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .Source = "Select * from TableName"   
            .CursorType = adOpenDynamic           
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient         
            .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
            .Open
        End With

       'disconnect the recordset and close the connection
        Set rsSQL.ActiveConnection = Nothing

        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing

        rsIn.MoveFirst    

        rsSQL.MoveLast

        'Add the records from the passed recordset to the SQL recordset
        Do While Not rsIn.EOF

            With rsSQL 
                   .AddNew

                   .Fields("FieldName1").Value = rsIn.Fields("FieldName1").Value
                   .Fields("FieldName2").Value = rsIn.Fields("FieldName2").Value
                   .Fields("FieldName3").Value = rsIn.Fields("FieldName3").Value
                   .Fields("FieldName4").Value = rsIn.Fields("FieldName4").Value
                   .Fields("FieldName5").Value = rsIn.Fields("FieldName5").Value
                   .Fields("FieldName6").Value = rsIn.Fields("FieldName6").Value
                   .Fields("FieldName7").Value = rsIn.Fields("FieldName7").Value
            End With 

            rsIn.MoveNext
        Loop

    rsSQL.UpdateBatch

    MsgBox "The data has successfully been saved to the SQL Server", _ 
    vbInformation + vbOKOnly,"Alert: Upload Successful"

exiting:
    If cn.State > 0 Then cn.Close
    If rsIn.State > 0 Then rsIn.Close
    If rsSQL.State > 0 Then rsSQL.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rsIn = Nothing
    Set rsSQL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not loading from a worksheet (its from a userform) and since my recordset is already open, its taking exception to the .Source property, telling me 'Operation is not allowed when the object is open' I tried setting these rs parameters at the top of my code too when I first create the rs but that resulted in the same error message I originally received, Insufficient base table information for updating or refreshing.

Do I need to set the source, cursorType, cursorLocation, or Locktype when I originally create my new recordset? Right now I don't set those so i'm assuming they are default.

Comment: @user3566139 Gotcha. Are you getting the data in an array from a list box? Is it a one dimensional array or two dimensional array?

Comment: No array, just a series of text boxes and combo boxes. I will eventually be grabbing large amounts of data via the XML trick above but the issue i'm currently working to solve is manually populating a new recordset, then connecting it and updating my table.

Comment: OK that makes more sense. The code I have above is actually slightly incorrect, which is my bad. I am on my way home from work and as soon as I get home in just a few minutes I will correct the code above and provide code for adding array an array of values.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, I think I'm ok with the populating of the recordset, but once I've got a populated and disconnected recordset, i'm missing something in the connection to the database and table in question. I think that source line you referenced is key, but my recordset is already opened at that point which throws an error. I tried closing the recordset right before that, and I didn't get an error, but I lost the data that was in the recordset, so nothing obviously was loaded into my table.

Comment: I elaborated more in my OP about the timing of when i'd like to open the connection and update the data. Essentially some recordsets I use I only use for quick filtering and sorting and those recordsets never get sent to a database. There are others however, that I wil l populate with the intent of sending them to the database. those recordsets i'd like to send to another sub() where the connection is established and data updated before closing the connection back down. For that reason, i'd like to have a disconnected rs that I send for connection at the end.

Comment: Interesting. So I pass my populated rs (rsIn in your example code) into the function where my connection takes place, but I need to create a new rs (rsSQL) with source "Select * FROM table_name" and then copy the contents from rsIn to rsSQL and then UpdateBatch with rsSQL? I guess what I was hoping to find was a way to simply connect rsIn all by itself - which maybe isn't possible if it was never connected in the first place. In this case, i'd probably be better suited to just load new records into rsSQL from scratch rather than load rsIn and then copy those contents to rsSQL.

Comment: @user3566139 Since `rsIn` is a disconnected recordset, which I am assuming it was "created from scratch" (a disconnected recordset) as you state in your question, then the only way to get the contents of the disconnected recordset into SQL, is to connect to the table that you want to populate, add the contents of the disconnected recordset to the SQL recordset, then update batch. Looping through the disconnected recordset and adding to the SQL recordset is still waaaayyy faster than using `insert Into` for each record.

Comment: Agreed. But your solution requires two recordset objects, rsIn and rsSQL. I was looking for a way to create and populate rsIn and then just connect that to my db. If I need rsSQL to do that, i'd rather just create rsSQL and add my new records to that rather than create and populate rsIn, then create rsSQL then copy rsIn to rsSQL then UpdateBatch. It doesn't sound like I can take rsIn, load it, and then connect it for updateBatch without a helper rs object.

Comment: @user3566139 Yea, unfortunately it's not possible to do it that way. There is an alternative. You could initialize an array variable (let's call it `arryRecorset`), then take your disconnected recordset, and do `arryRecorset = recordset.GetRows`, which returns an Un-transposed 2-D array. You could then build a delimited string from the array using a custom join string function, then pass the string to a Stored procedure that uses `XML` to parse the string into rows and columns, and then `Insert Into` without a loop. I have done this, for an array with over 200,000 rows and it ran in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get this to work was by running a query to build the structure of my Recordset.  So your code becomes something like this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   cn.ConnectionString = "<your connection string>"
   cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
   cn.Open

   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
   rs.Open "select * from states where 1<>1", , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
   rs.AddNew Array("Abbrev", "Name", "Region", "SchoolDataDirect"), Array("TN", "TestName", "MyRegion", 1)
   Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

   cn.Close

   ImportRS rs
End Sub

Private Sub ImportRS(ByRef rs As ADODB.Recordset)
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   cn.ConnectionString = "<your connection string>"
   cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
   cn.Open

   Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
   rs.UpdateBatch
   Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

   cn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, that's the only way I could get it to work as well. Since it seems I need to open the connection first to build the structure of the recordset I chose not to close the recordset but rather populate it real time and then UpdateBatch.

Comment: @user3566139 If this answer solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.